# Random predictions from linear model in R

Tags: r, glm, predict

I have some data with some missing values for one variable, and I want to be able to create (random) predictions for what these could be. Here's my first thought:

```
# miss indicates where the observations with missing response are
library(MASS)
model <- glm.nb(data[-miss,4] ~ ., data=data[-miss,-4])
predict(model, newdata=data[miss,-4])
```

However, if I repeat the last line, it gives the same answers over and over - it appears to give the predicted mean of responses given that data and the model. I want a random prediction which incorporates variance i.e. a random draw from the distribution of the response of an observation with such predictors under the given model.

It could have something to do with the pred.var argument, but I'm unsure how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have data like this:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=(1:20)*0.1)
dd$y <- rnbinom(20,mu=exp(dd$x),size=1)
## make some missing values
miss <- c(2,3,5)
dd$y[miss] <- NA
```

Now fit a model:

```
m1 <- MASS::glm.nb(y~x,dd,na.action=na.exclude)
```

Now use predictions from that model to get the expected *mean* value and `rnbinom` to generate the random values ...

```
p <- predict(m1,newdata=dd,type="response")
randvals <- rnbinom(length(p),mu=p,size=m1$theta)
```

(This gives random values for every element, not just the missing ones, but obviously you can pick out just the ones you want ...) It would be nice if the `simulate` method did this, but it's not quite flexible enough ...